# What was the reasoning behind Sookie's decision?

Tags: plot-explanation, true-blood

At the end of season 4, we see Tara get fatally wounded in the back of the head from a shotgun blast from Debbie, aiming for Sookie.

After the initial shock, Pam arrives just in time, looking for Eric.  However, instead of doing the usual 'let them drink your blood to heal'; Sookie, in a panic, tells Pam to raise her as a Vampire instead.

**Why?**

Knowing Tara's past with vampires, and usually how simplistic it is for friendly vampires to let the wounded drink their blood for health, would Sookie decide to turn her best friend into a Vampire?

Is it because Tara is dead, or rather, close enough to death that even Vampire blood cannot save her?  Or is this merely a slip-up on Sookie's part, panicking over her best friend's condition?

Comment: [Topic of the Week Winner](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/479/topic-of-the-week)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that Sookie either knows or assumes that Tara is too far gone or would be dead before the blood could take affect. This is backed up by a couple of points in the series that is takes a while for the blood to work, and more than a bit is needed.

Sookie knows of Tara's dealing with vampires, but I assume her desire to save her childhood friend over-rode her knowledge that Tara had very bad dealings with vampires.

IMHO I would not be surprised if both Tara and Pam leave the show by the end of this season, it seems to be heading that way.